# Sudden double space in ShareLatex

Tags: spacing, errors, sharelatex

I'm writing a book and sometimes I just have some double space between paragraphs. I don't know how to fix it.

My book code concerning the chapter format is:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% Not necessary...
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps add the `\raggedbottom` directive in the preamble.

Comment: it will be unrelated to sharelatex, and isn't clearly related to the code you have posted. Please add a small complete document here that shows the problem. but as Bernard says book classes are usually set flushbottom so if the only way to achieve a full page is to stretch the inter-paragraph space then that will be stretched.